# AppleScript and rsync - trouble excluding list of directories

Tags: applescript, rsync

i'm having trouble telling rsync to exclude a list of directories from the sync process. I'm feeding it a text file using the exclude-from command, but it seems to be ignoring it.

here's the code I'm trying to use in applescript:

```
set log_file to "/Users/x/Sync Test Folder/log.txt"
set exclude_file to "/Users/x/Sync Test Folder/log2.txt"
set target_folder to "/Users/x/Sync Test Folder"
set source_folder to "/Users/x/source_test/sub/" 

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set currentTab to do script "rsync" & " -avPhr " & "--include '*/' --exclude='*' --exclude-from=" & quoted form of exclude_file & " --log-file= " & quoted form of log_file & " " & quoted form of source_folder & " " & quoted form of target_folder & " >>" & quoted form of log_file
end tell
```

Right now i'm manually typing in the log2.txt file the name of the directory i want to exclude as /directory_2/ but this doesn't seem to work.

can someone help point out what might be wrong?

thanks

Comment: So the string you're sending to the `do script` evaluates to this: `rsync -avPhr --include '*/' --exclude='*' --exclude-from='/Users/x/Sync Test Folder/log2.txt' --log-file= '/Users/x/Sync Test Folder/log.txt' '/Users/x/source_test/sub/' '/Users/x/Sync Test Folder' >>'/Users/x/Sync Test Folder/log.txt'`.  I notice a missing `=` after `--include`; and whitespace after `--log-file=`. These may or may not matter, I'm not sure but the man page was consistent with its syntax.  Beyond that, does the command work when entered directly into _Terminal_ ?

Comment: Also, what is the contents of your `log2.txt` file ?  Should we check it for errors ?  Could you try excluding the directories using multiple `--exclude` options instead of an `--exclude-from` ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer the problem. It turns out the order in which you use the include or exclude/exclude-from statements is important. So by just moving the exclude statements to the beginning of the command and the include statement to the end, everything works as expected.